# How to use Rules to change the value of entity reference’s field?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

I have two content types (*Inventory* and *Sales*). In *Sales*, I referenced *Inventory* using the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module.

In *Inventory*, I have a stock_available (integer) field. In *Sales*, I also have the same field, so that I can automatically populate its value from *Inventory* using the [Entity reference autofill](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autofill) module.

When I add a new *Sales* node, I want to adjust the value of stock_available  in the referenced *Inventory*, so that gradually it becomes zero in the referenced *Inventory* node.

I know how to set value/calculated value from other filed within same content type, by using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

I have no idea how I can do same things to targeted entity reference node. I think it's possible by just rule configuration. Please let me know if something needs to change to get same output that I expected.

Answer (score 0):

## Step 1: Create a Rules Component

Create a Rules Component (of type "action set") like so:

- Parameters are "`node`" and "`stock decrease`".
- Rules Action = "*set value/calculated value from other filed within same content type*" **(*)**.

Here is a prototype of such Rules Component:

```
{ "rules_decrease_stock" : {
    "LABEL" : "Decrease Stock",
    "PLUGIN" : "action set",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "node_to_update" : { "label" : "Node to be updated", "type" : "node" },
      "stock_decrease" : { "label" : "Stock decrease", "type" : "integer" }
    },
    "ACTION SET" : [
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Something just got sold, so please decrease the stock for node with id [node-to-update:nid] with an amount of \r\n[stock-decrease:value] units. To actually do so, replace this (informational) Rules Action with setting the appropriate value for the appropriate field ..." } }
    ]
  }
}
```

The actual action only displays a Drupal message (to show the values of the variables passed to it). Replace that action with the actual update of your inventory node **(*)**.

## Step 2: Create a Rule

Create a rule with Rules Event something like "after updating a node of content type "Sales". Maybe also some Rules Condition like "`stock_available`" is updated (checked if the unsaved value differs from the saved value). And add these Rules Actions:

- Update the `stock_available` in your Sales content type **(*)**.
- Perform the Rules Component (from step 1), whereas you pass these 2 **parameters**:

  - the `node`, which you can pass via the value (token) of the entity reference.
  - the `stock decrease` amount (which is identical).

**(*)**: you indicated in your question you know how to do that ...

Comment: Sir, I am confused, if it's possible please explain it little more (screenshot, if possible). If I create rules components then what "Component plugin" should I choose? and in DATA TYPE what I choose? In action within  Components, I didn't find filed "stock_available" in Data selector. how to pass parameters? Actually I need to update/change value to filed in Inventory content type, when I add sales content (Stock Available - Sales Quantity). I hope you understand me now.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Yeah, I solve this problem but without using component option. I was found a tutorial on this, just with little change, I was able to get expected output. Should I write those step here?